# Can I customize Google Movies to only show movies from a certain list of cinemas?

Tags: google-movies

Google Movies shows me the list of movies playing in theaters in my city. That's all nice and well, but I have a certain card that lets me go in free at some of the cinemas. Is there a way to customize Google Movies and only let it show movies from those cinemas where I can get in free?

If it can't be done, is there a way to do it with another application?

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to limit the search to one theatre chain by use `at {name}` in the search.

Example:

```
no good deed at regal

http://www.google.com/movies?near=&q=no+good+deed+at+regal
```

Limits the list to only Regal Cinemas in my general search area.

Otherwise, no, it doesn't appear that you can customize the search to "all movies from subset of theatres". I don't recall any other "movie-finder" tool I've ever used having such a utility either, but that's not to say they might not be out there.

Comment: Thanks. That's useful albeit not enough since the subset of theaters my pass allows me to get into for free is not so homogeneous.